# Drupal 7 webform Version: 7.x-4.5 not sending email

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

After updating to Webform Version: 7.x-4.5 the email functionality is not working, which I assume it could be due to change in tokens.

I have a Webform as block a  which is attached to product content type and want to send the contact form information which is webform to current node author.

I am using [current-page:node:author:mail] token as a hidden field in the webform, which used to work until I update to new version of webform and since then the worbfrom stop sending email to author email.

What I am doing:

In the webofrm I have a hidden field author_mail where the default value is set to [current-page:node:author:mail]

[image]

At the Webform email setting I set E-mail to address to Component: Author Mail.
[image]

Any idea what token to use if not [current-page:node:author:mail]?

Is there any way to send the Webfrom content to current page author email?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make token `[current-page:node:author:mail]` working, you need to apply [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/919760#comment-9973163) Token module patch.

[Source](http://www.jasom.net/webform-is-submitted-send-email-to-the-current-node-author).